# Electron PDF window navigate to page number possible?

Tags: electron

Is it possible to jump to PDF page number using the electron PDF window library?https://github.com/gerhardberger/electron-pdf-window

Comment: From a quick glance at the source code, no it doesn't. You can extend it, if that is what you need. Look at the code for pdfjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in support of PDF viewer in election version 3.1.7 use the mentioned plugin above. To use PDF navigation in URL, to navigate using file:pathofyour.pdf#page=pagenumber just uncomment the content in isPDF() function and replace it with resolve(true)

Electron is a great way to develope cross platform applications but the api is not really mature and is alternated a way to often with every major release in my opinion